# Transporting an airsoft gun from the US to Israel

Tags: air-travel, usa, luggage, israel

There was a question about traveling with a gun:

[Can Somebody travel with their gun internationally?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17817/can-somebody-travel-with-their-gun-internationally)

What procedures, if any, does one need to follow to bring an airsoft gun from the US into Israel on an airplane?

P.S. It will be transported in the checked luggage if at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Airsoft guns, are considered a dangerous toy in Israel, so you won't be able to import it without a proper permit from the Israeli authorities.

[Here is a list(in Hebrew)](http://www.moital.gov.il/NR/exeres/0B428AD4-B5AB-400C-8EE3-5CF7358620E3.htm) from the ministry of industry trade & labor site of examples of dangerous toys. You can see on the list also tear gas canisters and lighters in the shape of a gun and other toys that look like real guns.

If you want, [here is the form](http://mops.gov.il/Documents/Publications/Forms/FireArms/FA_BusinessRequests/ImportingLicenseReq.pdf) you need to feel to request a licence (in Hebrew), and [a blog post](http://edmuntas.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/blog-post_20.html) containing explanations on the process of importing an airsoft gun (also in Hebrew).

Comment: Tear gas is a *toy*?

Comment: Tear gas in the form of a gun is classified as a **Dangerous Toy** together with replica guns, air soft guns, gun lighters ect. This is not the case for tear gas that comes in other non-gun like form.

Comment: @user2357112 People have strange hobbies.

Answer (score 4):

Airsoft guns, as well as being working pellet guns, are replica guns in the sense that they look like the real thing. [Replica guns must be treated in the same way as guns when carried on an aircraft](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/airlines-firearm-rules-1590.html). [See also here](http://www.seatguru.com/articles/tsa_prohibited_items.php#firearms).

You should probably be aware that [importing Airsoft guns to Israel may not be legal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_issues_in_airsoft#Israel).

Comment: Remind me not to visit israel. Not only is it hot.....I have heat here in Texas, but no airsoft or airguns?.......do not approve.

Comment: Airsoft are not just airguns. It's only importing them that may be illegal in Israel, but almost every country in the world has some sort of restriction on them.

Comment: Comments are not for chat. We have a chat forum for that.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it is legal here but I don't think you will be caught either, my friend ordered an airsoft gun and it arrived. Some other friend bought one when he was in Greece and brought it here without problems. So you don't have to worry about it.